# Unable to find expansion in regular perturbation problem

Tags: asymptotics, mathematical-modeling, perturbation-theory

> Consider the equation: $\varepsilon^{3}x+x=1$.
>
> 1. Look for a rescaling of this equation in the form $x = \varepsilon^n X$ with $X \in O(1)$ and explain what value $n$ should take to find two more solutions.

---

I've plugged in the substitution into the original equation to get:

$$ \varepsilon^{n+3}X + \varepsilon^{n}X = 1 $$

but I don't know how to *explain* a value for $n$ that will yield two more solutions.

What am I supposed to be looking for here?

I would be very grateful if someone is able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try balancing each pair of terms in the equation. There are three options. One of those options will give you the right answer.

Comment: By the way, are you sure there isn't an $x^3$ in the equation?

Comment: @AntonioVargas thanks I was able to find the correct balance and the question makes sense to me now. Also yes, the equation is without an ${x^3}$ term, the first part of the question asked if the equation was regular so maybe they omitted the ${x^3}$ term on purpose to trick ppl out